# autocomplete text view not working

Tags: android

On my contact list application i try to use autocompletetextview when making search of contacts but is not working

here is my Search.java:

```
public class Search extends  ListActivity {

 private static int[] TO = {R.id.name };
private static String[] FROM = {DbConstants.NAME, DbConstants.PHONE, DbConstants.EMAIL,_ID};
private Button sButton;

 private ListView lv1;
 private static SQLiteDatabase db;
  private DbCreate contacts;
  private Cursor cursor;
  private AutoCompleteTextView searchText;
  protected SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,new String[] {DbConstants.NAME});
    searchText=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
    searchText.setAdapter(adapter);

    sButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    sButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            showDatabaseContent();
              lv1 = getListView();

              lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }
    });





}
```

And here is my search.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"           android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <LinearLayout 
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <AutoCompleteTextView
     android:id="@+id/searchtext"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:hint="@string/searchDefault">

     <requestFocus />
         </AutoCompleteTextView> 
       <Button android:id="@+id/searchButton" 
      android:icon="@drawable/search" 
       android:text="Search"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/empt" />
        <ListView
 android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearL ayout>
```

I dont get any error but search anly works when i press search button.but when i start typing a name nothing happens.where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are these methods for `AutoComplete TextView`

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
  int after) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Just refer this basic [Example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/example-of-autocompletetextview.html)

Comment: Why Android Developer site didn't mention that in the example. And they say that it will work!! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

Comment: Forget the last comment. check my answer.

Comment: @hasan Where i want to check it?

Comment: I did follow the android developer site example and used android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 which was setting background and text with white colour. I change it to android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line and all worked fine. I didn't answer cause that's wasn't our friend problem right here

Answer (score 3):

Add the below line in your XML file under **AutoCompleteTextView**

```
android:completionThreshold="1"
```

it may work, try it.